# Sealing thrips out of monitors

Tags: computer-hardware

I don't know if this is the correct forum as I can't find any suitable tags.

We operate some of our equipment in fields inside tents.   Our big problem is thrips/thunder flies.  They somehow make it into the inside of the LCD monitors.  This happens to laptops too.

It is quite amusing and an the same time annoying that these creatures crawl around inside the screens.  If you press the monitor behind the thrip, it makes them move somewhere else.  If you press too close, it squashes the thrip and its corpse will be there forever.  Sometimes they just die in there.

We have a bunch of monitors with dead thrips inside which are for field use only.  The main problem is when you look at data and wonder is that 112 or 1.2 because the thrip is over the 1 or .  You have to move the text up or down to make sure - wastes a lot of time.  Also when you are looking at charts, the thrip corpses obscure the display.

We have tried sealing the edges with duck/duct tape but still the little buggers manage to get in.  The only way in I can think of is through the air vent which must not be covered.

I'm just wondering what I can cover the vents with that will still allow airflow but stop the thrips from entering.

Comment: You can get sealed enclosures with controlled venting... Cost +++ but accuracy & time may be worth more... you choose.

Comment: Thrips are largely attracted by visual clues. They are particular to certain colors. Change the monitor colors to avoid those that draw thrips - tent color also. Agricultural thrip traps use attractive colors, use those traps near the monitors. Bugs are about management, not total control. They can be bribed and conned, but usually not eradicated without dire side effects.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/45727174_Attraction_of_Color_Traps_to_Thrips_Species_Thysanoptera_Thripidae_on_Brassica_Crops_in_Colorado

Comment: You could try putting some permethrin treated strips on/in the monitors?

Comment: @PhilSweet - this used to happen when my laptop was monochrome with a backlit LCD.  I'm just wondering if it is the light.  It is fine during the day: they normally enter in the evenings.

Comment: It is only one particular type of thrip that we call thunder-flies in the UK that seems to enter the monitor.  There are a couple of pictures in this publication of a local newspaper https://www.grimsbytelegraph.co.uk/news/local-news/you-need-know-annoying-little-1815703